# How to extend wayland/weston to control x,y position of a window/surface

Tags: wayland, qtwayland

I'm trying to control the x,y position through `weston/desktop-shell/shell.c` in `weston_view_set_initial_position(...)`.

What I planned to do is simply extend the data structures which pass down the surface width/height by adding global x/y position.

I'm using qt/qml application. the top level api is `qwindow.setX()`.

The idea comes from: [How do I set the x,y coordinates of a window in Wayland?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633817/how-do-i-set-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-window-in-wayland/39988987)

`@mpr` mentioned it's too much to bite.

If anyone can explain how big it is or any potential difficulties, I will be grateful.